# How we can display associated product with radio buttons instead of Dropdown at Product View Page?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, bundled-product

I want to show associated product as like following manner. So user can select anyone product for cart. Which product type will be useful to show such products? Configurable or Bundle ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A popular blog from Inchoo is already there, you can check that out:

- http://inchoo.net/magento/configurable-product-modification-in-magento/